# How to reuse HTTP request instance in Go

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-http

I'm building an API that scrapes some data off a webpage.

To do so, i need to send a GET request to a home page, scrape a 'RequestVerificationToken' from the HTML, then send another POST request to the same URL with a username, password, and the RequestVerificationToken.

I've been able to do this previously with Python:

```py
session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
parser = createBS4Parser(result.text)
return parser.find('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})["value"]

 pageDOM = session_requests.post(
        LOGIN_URL,
        data=requestPayload, //RequestVerificationToken is in here
        headers=requestHeaders
 )
```

It seems like when i reuse the `session_requests` variable in Python, it's reusing the previous instance of the HTTP request.

However, when i try to do this in Go, I get an error due to an invalid token. I assume that this is because for the POST request, Go is using a new instance.

Is there any way I can get the same behavior from Go as I was with Python?

Comment: A "session" is a higher level construct/idea than a HTTP request. You will have to implement sessions somehow.

Comment: Update: I ended up just attaching the cookies from the first request onto the second request which made it so that the RequestVerificationToken stayed the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 package main

 import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

   "github.com/gocolly/colly"
   "github.com/gocolly/colly/proxy"
     )

  func main() {
//initiates the configuration
c := colly.NewCollector(colly.AllowURLRevisit())
//defining the proxy chain
revpro, err := proxy.RoundRobinProxySwitcher("socks5://127.0.0.1:9050", "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
c.SetProxyFunc(revpro)
//parsing the required field from html we are extracting the csrf_token required for the login
c.OnHTML("form[role=form] input[type=hidden][name=CSRF_TOKEN]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
    csrftok := e.Attr("value")
    fmt.Println(csrftok)
    //posting the csrf value along with password
    err := c.Post("https://www.something.com/login.jsp", map[string]string{"CSRF_TOKEN": csrftok, "username": "username", "password": "password"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return
})
//The website to visit
c.Visit("https://www.something.com/login.jsp")
//maintaining the connection using clone not initiating a callback request
d := c.Clone()
d.OnHTML("a[href]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
    link := e.Attr("href")
    fmt.Printf("Link found: %q -> %s\n", e.Text, link)

})

d.Visit("https://skkskskskk.htm")
  }
```